# Does creating a new wiki summary without description count in the Research Assistant badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges

Recently I was awarded a Research Assistant badge but I would not think that I've edited 50+ tag wikis. If I'm right creating a new tag with only an excerpt creates an empty tag wiki description too.

[An answer about this badge on StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/169573) mentions that

> the badge counts distinct tag wikis you edit excluding excerpts.

So, creating a new wiki summary without description counts in the Research Assistant badge by design or is it just a bug?

Comment: Yeah, looks like you only created 18 actual wiki edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>At the moment we are not going to implement this because evaluating the content of each edit to determine only the significant ones would generate 3 times the SQL load for little gain.</strike>

---

We've found a way (kudos Nick Craver) to implement this more efficiently and it will be rolled out in the next deployment. Old awarded badges will not be revoked.